# Shell script: Check if data in columns `X` from two CSV files are matched

Tags: bash, awk, sed

For example I have

`a.txt`:

```
1 21 34
1 22 21
2 32 76
2 12 76
...
```

`b.txt`:

```
1 99 73
1 32 27
2 55 76
2 76 12
...
```

Expected output:

```
$ ./some_script 1 a.txt b.txt
0 # matched
# compare data in #1 column of a.txt to data in #1 column of b.txt
# data: a.txt  b.txt
#       1      1
#       1      1
#       2      2
#       2      2
$ ./some_script 2 a.txt b.txt
1 # not matched
$ ./some_script 3 a.txt b.txt
1 # not matched
```

where parameters `1`, `2`, and `3` are column numbers.

Let's say, the `some_script` just did comparison between data in the same column from files `a.txt` and `b.txt`.

I need some program written in either `bash`, `sed`, or `awk` (or another possible programs) to do this job.

Comment: Maybe you can share with us what you have tried so far? I also don't understand the expected output.

Comment: hint: use cut/awk to get only the columns you want to compare and then use cmp/diff on those files

Comment: so the result is just a string-marker `not matched` or `matched` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[ "$(cut -d' ' -f1 a.txt)" = "$(cut -d' ' -f1 b.txt)" ]; echo $?
```

**Explanation:**

1. `[ "string1" = "string2" ]` - The test command. If the `string1` equals to the `string2`, it returns `0`, else `1`. See `man test` for another information.
2. `cut -d' ' -f1 a.txt` - cut the first column from the file `a.txt`.

   - `-d' '` - set the field delimiter to the space.
   - `-f1` - select only the field number `1`. You can use a variable, instead of the number `1` in this case, like the `num=1; [ "$(cut -d' ' -f$num a.txt)" = "$(cut -d' ' -f$num b.txt)" ]; echo $?`.
3. `echo $?` - print the exit status of the last executed program.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a combination of `paste` and `awk` to achieve that

```
#!/bin/bash
[ -z "$1" -o -z "$2" -o -z "$3" ] && echo "Not enough arguments" && exit 1
[ ! -f "$2" -o  ! -f "$3" ] &&  echo "input file(s) don't exist" && exit 1

awk -v var="$1" '$var!=$(NF/2+var){flag=1;exit}
                 END{print flag;}' <(paste "$2" "$3")
```

Save the file as, say, `compare.sh`, make it an executable and then run it like

```
./compare.sh 3 a.txt b.txt
```

Comment: remove `print "1"` from first action block and, if condition from END block, instead just `print l`.  Also `l` is not a good single char variable name.

Comment: @karakfa Great suggestions indeed :) Incorporated.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple one line solution with bash and awk**

```
#!/bin/bash
[ "$(awk -F' ' "{print \$$1}" "$2")" == "$(awk -F' ' "{print \$$1}" "$3")" ] && echo 0 || echo 1
```

**Output**

```
./script 1 a.txt b.txt
0
./script 2 a.txt b.txt
1
./script 3 a.txt b.txt
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bash version using custom file descriptors and arrays:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3< "$2"
exec 4< "$3"

while read -ru3 -a a && read -ru4 -a b; do
    [ "${a[$(($1 - 1))]}" != "${b[$(($1 - 1))]}" ] && exit 1
done

exit 0
```