# Bug with RegExp in JavaScript when do global search

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript regex returning true.. then false.. then true.. etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630418/javascript-regex-returning-true-then-false-then-true-etc)

First of all, apologize for my bad english.

I'm trying to test string to match the pattern, so I has wrote this:

```js
var str = 'test';
var pattern = new RegExp('te', 'gi'); // yes, I know that simple 'i' will be good for this
```

But I have this unexpected results:

```js
>>> pattern.test(str)
true
>>> pattern.test(str)
false
>>> pattern.test(str)
true
```

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that RegEx isn't stateless. Your second `test` will continue to look for the next match in the string, and reports that it doesn't find any more. Further searches starts from the beginning, as `lastIndex` is reset when no match is found:

```
var pattern = /te/gi;

pattern.test('test');
>> true
pattern.lastIndex;
>> 2

pattern.test('test');
>> false
pattern.lastIndex;
>> 0
```

You'll notice how this changes when there are two matches, for instance:

```
var pattern = /t/gi;

pattern.test('test');
>> true
pattern.lastIndex;
>> 1

pattern.test('test');
>> true
pattern.lastIndex;
>> 4

pattern.test('test');
>> false
pattern.lastIndex;
>> 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you ran into this problem: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=237111

Removing the `g` parameter solves the issue. Basically its due to the `lastindex` property that remember last value every time you execute `test()` method

Comment: Thanx for answer!
Yes, I now that removing `g` solves this problem. But this bug appears also in Chrome...

Comment: It's not a bug. `test` and `exec` are designed to do that. Now let me go find the dupe...

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a bug. it's how regexp are implemented. Indeed it's an issue for OP

Comment: @F.Calderan, I forgot to direct my comment at GeorgeVinogradov, apologies for that.

Comment: @F.Calderan, it's realy the answer! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

To quote the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) (emphasis mine):

> When you want to know whether a pattern is found in a string use the test method (similar to the String.search method); for more information (but slower execution) use the exec method (similar to the String.match method). As with exec (or in combination with it), **test called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match.**

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended behavior of the [`RegExp.test(str)` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).  The regex instance (pattern) stores state which can be seen in the `lastIndex` property; each time you call "test" it updates that value and following calls with the same argument may or may not yield the same result:

```javascript
var str="test", pattern=new RegExp("te", "gi");
pattern.lastIndex; // => 0, since it hasn't found any matches yet.
pattern.test(str); // => true, since it matches at position "0".
pattern.lastIndex; // => 2, since the last match ended at position "1".
pattern.test(str); // => false, since there is no match after position "2".
```