# Mongoose Pagination is not working properly. It works when I refresh the page twice

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pagination

I am using mongoose pagination v5.0.3, node 9.3.0. I have this code for my blogs pagination:

```
 router.get('/pages/:page', function(req, res){
     var page = req.params.page > 0? req.params.page : 0;

     Blog.paginate({}, { page: page, limit: 2 })
       .then(function(data){
           res.render('blog/index', {blog: data.docs});
       }).catch(function(err){
           res.send(err)
     });
 });
```

This code works fine when the page loads, but when I refresh the page it loads 'not found page' 
    `app.get("*", function(req, res) {
       res.render("pages/404page");
    });`

Comment: Are you sure that app.get('*') is getting hit every second refresh? Put a console.log there.

Comment: yes. it is happening every second refresh. any ideas what might it be?

Comment: Need more code to see what exactly the issue is.

Comment: @thomann061 what code do you need? if you want  you can take a look https://github.com/Alisher778/vector-node repo

Comment: I figured it is because `express-params` package. `router.param('page', /[0-9]/g)`

Comment: Oh just saw this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually isn't that pagination function.  It is this regex statement above:

`router.param('page', /[0-9]/g)`

Remove the 'g' and it will work.

Explanation:

> You're using a g (global) RegExp. In JavaScript, global regexen have state: you call them (with exec, test etc.) the first time, you get the first match in a given string. Call them again and you get the next match, and so on until you get no match and it resets to the start of the next string.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630418/javascript-regex-returning-true-then-false-then-true-etc)

Btw, your regex only checks digits from 0-9, you might want that to take into digits higher than 9, if you are expecting more than 10 blog posts.

Comment: yes you are right. I just wanted to use numbers. Than you for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can do same using find skip and limit.

```
router.get('/pages/:page', function (req, res) {
    var page = req.params.page > 0 ? req.params.page : 0;
    var limit = 2;
    Blog.find({})
        .limit(limit)
        .skip(limit * page)
        .exec()
        .then(function (data) {
            res.render('blog/index', {
                blog: data.docs
            });
        }).catch(function (err) {
            res.send(err)
        });
});
```

Comment: I tried this method as well. But no luck. it is very interesting. why it is happening 1st time it loads correctly, second time it loads 404 page

Comment: so if second request comes page value is 404page?

Comment: yes. I mean if it is '/blog/pages/2' and if I refresh the page with the same url, it say the page not found

Comment: Can you console.log inside the app.all('*') to see what req.url is?