# condition is met even when is false

Tags: javascript, regex, if-statement, ibm-forms

I am trying to check if an input value is alphanumeric. According to regex101.com my regex should work. But all test results in "incorrect".

What am I doing wrong?

```js
var alphaNumeric = /^[a-z0-9]+$/gi;
var input = "123"; //page.input.getValue().toUpperCase();

console.log(input);

if (input.length == 3) {

  if (alphaNumeric.test(input)) {
    console.log("correct");
  } else {
    console.log("incorrect");
  }
} else {

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx for Javascript to allow only alphanumeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388996/regex-for-javascript-to-allow-only-alphanumeric)

Comment: `But all test results in "incorrect".` can give sample inputs that don't work?

Comment: It's not a duplicate. Please read my question.  @RuiJarimba

Comment: `page` is not defined, and what is `getValue()`?

Comment: It works! What output you got?

Comment: 123, AAA, !!! - These all results in incorrect.

Comment: @Andy it is an function of IBM forms to get an input value. The function works fine.

Comment: Your code is incomplete, as others have stated, so we are unable to test it with a view to reproducing the incorrect behaviour. I would suspect that you are not updating the value of `input` when the user submits the string to test?

Comment: Just tried with "123" and "AAA" and it works.

Comment: @RobinZigmond that's what the getValue() function does. I get the updated value but the if statement always results in incorrect.

Comment: I have updated your question, please try with Run code Snippet

Comment: well it works, returning "correct". @Joep - I know `getValue()` gets the current input, but unless you are calling that and putting its return value into the `input` variable, at the point you test, it'll just be testing against whatever the initial input value was. (Which I guess is the empty string.)

Comment: All thanks for your help. The issue had to do with the /g of the regex. @Noninka was correct. My new regex is: /^[a-z0-9]+$/i;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer of [@bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2630538/1241218

> You're using a g (global) RegExp.
>   In JavaScript, global regexen have state: you call them (with exec,
>   test etc.) the first time, you get the first match in a given string.
>   Call them again and you get the next match, and so on until you get no
>   match and it resets to the start of the next string. You can also
>   write regex.lastIndex= 0 to reset this state.
>
> (This is of course an absolutely terrible piece of design, guaranteed
>   to confuse and cause weird errors. Welcome to JavaScript!)
>
> You can omit the g from your RegExp, since you're only testing for one
>   match.

So in your case you will have different results on every try:

```js
    var alphaNumeric = /^[a-z0-9]+$/gi;
    var input = "123";
    console.log(input);
    if (input.length == 3) {
        for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
            if (alphaNumeric.test(input)) {
                console.log("correct");
            } else {
                console.log("incorrect");
            }
        }

    } else {
        
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of the global flag (you're matching start and end anyway)

```
var alphaNumeric = /^[a-z0-9]+$/i;
console.log(alphaNumeric.test("aaa")); // true
console.log(alphaNumeric.test("AAA")); // true
console.log(alphaNumeric.test("123")); // true
console.log(alphaNumeric.test("a1a1a1")); // true
console.log(alphaNumeric.test("ABC-123")); // false
```

Comment: The same conclusion as the accepted solution, why the downvote?